# How do I deal with SyntaxError: Unexpected token: Typo

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want to know the logic of my error and how should I write it instead, please. Thank You

**This is the question:**

Write a function called "findShortestOfThreeWords".
Given 3 strings, "findShortestOfThreeWords" returns the shortest of the given strings.
If there are ties, it should return the first word in the parameters list.

**The Error I get:**

/home/runner/Module-1/index.js:21
}esle{
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

**my code:**

```
function findShortestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3){
  //if word1 was less than or equal word2
    //return word1
  //else
    //return word2
  //if word1 is less than or equal word3
    //return word1
  //esle 
    //return word3
  //if word2 is less than or equal word3
    //return word2
  //else
    //return word3

if(word1.length <= word2.length){
  return word1;
}else{
  return word2;
}if(word1.length <= word3.length){
  return word1;
}esle{
  return word3;
}if(word2.length <= word3.length ){
  return word2;
}else{
  return word3;
}
  
}

var output = findShortestOfThreeWords('a', 'two', 'three');
console.log(output); // --> 'a'
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix the typo? Found `esle` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `esle` to `else`

```js
function findShortestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3){
  //if word1 was less than or equal word2
    //return word1
  //else
    //return word2
  //if word1 is less than or equal word3
    //return word1
  //esle 
    //return word3
  //if word2 is less than or equal word3
    //return word2
  //else
    //return word3

if(word1.length <= word2.length){
  return word1;
}else{
  return word2;
}if(word1.length <= word3.length){
  return word1;
}else{
  return word3;
}if(word2.length <= word3.length ){
  return word2;
}else{
  return word3;
}
  
}

var output = findShortestOfThreeWords('a', 'two', 'three');
console.log(output); // --> 'a'
```

Comment: Please just vote to close as a typo

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad that it was a typo. :)

Answer (score -1):

it seems that there is a typo in your code:
**esle**{
return word3;

try changing it to else

Comment: OMG :). Thank you